# Automatically create a Python class based on other class

Tags: python, generics, python-typing, mapped-types

In a Python script I am comparing two messages (expected and actual) to find fields that do not match.
I have a data class for actual message (I am using attrs, but @dataclass can also be used) which is read from file:

```py
@define
class Message:
  id: str
  value_1: int
  value_2: int
  value_3: float
```

Expected message is built inside the script and it has a slightly different requirement. Each field can also accept a special value "AnyValue", which means that it matches any value.
So expected class should be like this:

```py
@define
class ExpectedMessage:
  id: str | AnyValue
  value_1: int | AnyValue
  value_2: int | AnyValue
  value_3: float | AnyValue
```

Unfortunately, this is a lot of duplication (actually there are many such messages, and each have lots of fields). It would be great if I can come up with a solution where I would not need to write the class twice.

In Typescript this can be done very easily using Mapped Types:

```js
type Message = {
  id: string;
  value_1: number;
  value_2: number;
  value_3: number;
}

type Expected<T> = {
  [Key in keyof T]: T[Key] | AnyValue;
}
type ExpectedMessage = Expected<Message>;
```

In Python I came up with a following solution using generics, but it is not perfect:

```py
T = TypeVar('T')

@define
class Message(Generic[T]):
  id: str | T
  value_1: int | T
  value_2: int | T
  value_3: float | T

ActualMessage = Message[NoReturn]  # "str | NoReturn" == "str"
ExpectedMessage = Message[AnyValue]
```

Maybe anybody has a better solution or can suggest a different approach completely.
Main requirement is that everything should be type safe.

Comment: I don't understand what your issue is with the generic solution. Could you elaborate on what exactly you mean, when you say _"it is not perfect"_? Because it seems to solve your problem and fulfill your secondary requirements, while also being very concise and readable (as opposed to the TypeScript version).

Comment: For me the Typescript version is more elegant. We define the main type normally and then from that we can derive the expected type using Expected<T> mapping (it would work on any type, even external types written by others). On the contrary, on Python we need to add " | T" to each property and then derive both actual and expected types from that. It requires to write the classes in a certain way and it can be weird to someone not familiar with the codebase.

Comment: _"It requires me to write the classes a certain way and it can be weird [...]"_ Those are not arguments. I understand that being used to a certain way of doing things can make other way feel unfamiliar. But you did not answer my question. What problems does your generic class solution cause? Where does it fall short?

Comment: If you **really** need such processing instead of (very clean - your current solution is awesome, IMO) generic implementation, you can always write a `mypy` plugin with `get_class_decorator_hook` (and I'd add a separate deco for that, no-op at runtime, to avoid modifying external decorator behaviour in case you have `define` without such requirement somewhere). This plugin should just loop over all attributes and adjust the type to `UnionType` with `AnyValue`.

Comment: @SUTerliakov thank you for the suggestion. I think I will keep using my solution, as I don't want the approach to be dependent on specific type checker. But it is interesting that such solution is also possible.